# In Pine, why strategy entering on odd indexed bar eventhough the condition for entry was on even?

Tags: pine-script

I my code, I clearly specify that the entry order should be made on an **even bar**

```
//@version=5
strategy("TEST STRATEGY 2", overlay=true)


backtestStartDate = input.time(timestamp("01 Apr 2023 12:05:00 GMT+02:00"), title="Start Date", group="Backtest Time Period")
backtestEndDate = input.time(timestamp("01 Apr 2023 12:15:00 GMT+02:00"), title="End Date", group="Backtest Time Period")
inTradeWindow = time > backtestStartDate and time <= backtestEndDate


if inTradeWindow


    if bar_index % 2 == 0
        strategy.entry("My Long Entry", strategy.long)
    else
        strategy.close("My Short Entry")


    a = str.tostring(bar_index)
    label.new(bar_index, na, a, yloc = yloc.abovebar, size = size.normal,textcolor = color.white)
```

Yet, the contrary happens:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your script is ok, the test is made on an even bar, you can see the start value of your trade is on the close of the even bar.
TradingView simply note the beginning of your trade at the entry point of the next bar.
It can be visually odd but the result is the same.

Comment: well, the small right arrow is on the open of the bar 17735, I agree it's at the same level of the close of 17734, but still... anyway